# The inequality $\Pi (1-\frac{1}{a_i})^{x_i} \le \Pi (1-\frac{1}{b_j})^{y_j} $ hold?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inequalities, euler-product

> > **Question:** Are the properties as follows holds?

**Version 1:** the answer by Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen

Let $P$ be a positive integers. We written: $P=$ $a_1^{x_1}a_2^{x_2}...a_n^{x_n}$ $=b_1^{y_1}b_2^{y_2}...b_k^{y_k}$  where $a_i, b_j$ are integers greater than $1$.

if $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i \le \prod_{j=1}^k b_j $ then

1) $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i}) \le \prod_{j=1}^k (1-\frac{1}{b_j}) $$

2) $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i})^{x_i} \le \prod_{j=1}^k (1-\frac{1}{b_j})^{y_j} $$

3) $$\frac{\varphi(P)}{P} \le \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i})$$

Where $\varphi(P)$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $P$

**Comment:** The answer of Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen is:

> No, let $b_1,b_2,a_1,a_2$ be $2,6,3,4$. Then $$ (1-1/2)(1-1/6)=5/12
>  \not\ge    1/2=(1-1/3)(1-1/4) $$

But I think the asnswer is not counter example. Because $2.6 \le 3.4$ we can write

$$ (1-1/2)(1-1/6)=5/12
\le  1/2=(1-1/3)(1-1/4) $$.

To clearly I changes the question as follows:

**Version 2:**

Let $P$ be a positive integers. We written: $P=$ $a_1^{x_1}a_2^{x_2}...a_n^{x_n}$ $=b_1^{y_1}b_2^{y_2}...b_k^{y_k}$  where $a_i, b_j$ are integers greater than $1$.

> if $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i < \prod_{j=1}^k b_j $ and $a_i \le b_j$ then

1) $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i}) \le \prod_{j=1}^k (1-\frac{1}{b_j}) $$

2) $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i})^{x_i} \le \prod_{j=1}^k (1-\frac{1}{b_j})^{y_j} $$

3) $$\frac{\varphi(P)}{P} \le \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i})$$

Where $\varphi(P)$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $P$

Comment: Can you kindly inform us about possible applications of these inequalities? Aren't the ones art for art's sake? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2^46^118^1=3^34^116^1(=2^63^3)$.

$2\cdot6\cdot18=216>192=3\cdot4\cdot16$.

$(1/2)(5/6)(17/18)=85/216<15/32=(2/3)(3/4)(15/16)$.

Concerning the question about the phi-function, for $$n=2^{28}3^{16}=4\times6\times8\times9\times12\times16\times18\times24\times27\times32\times36\times48\times54$$ we have $${\phi(n)\over n}={1\over3}=.333\dots>.32956\dots={3\over4}\cdot{5\over6}\cdot\cdots\cdot{53\over54}$$

Comment: I belive the Euler's totient function is minimum:

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean $\frac{\varphi(A)}{A} \le \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i})$

Where $\varphi(A)$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: But what is $A$?

Comment: I am sorry I mean $\frac{\varphi(P)}{P} \le \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_i})$

Answer (score 6):

Answer to Version 1 of the question:

No, let $b_1,b_2,a_1,a_2$ be $2,6,3,4$.
Then
$$
(1-1/2)(1-1/6)=5/12 \not\ge    1/2=(1-1/3)(1-1/4).
$$

Comment: In other words, the simplest possible example satisfying the hypothesis already fails to satisfy the conclusion.

Comment: do I want correct $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i \le \prod_{j=1}^k b_j $ to $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i < \prod_{j=1}^k b_j $ and $a_i \le b_j$. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Dear @BjørnKjos-Hanssen , because $2.6 \ge \le = 3.4$ so $(1-1/2)(1-1/6)=5/12 \not\ge    1/2=(1-1/3)(1-1/4)$ is not counter example.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen I change my question. If You delete the answer, I will delete version 1 thank you. I am sorry.

Comment: I guess we can have one answer for each version, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2951/altering-the-question-in-a-way-that-makes-an-answer-obsolete

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Ok, But I think your answer (now) is not answer. Because $a.b=c.d$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(a,b)>f(c,d)$ or $f(a,b)<f(c,d)$ also true.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen ecause $2.6 \le 3.4$ we can write $ (1-1/2)(1-1/6)=5/12
\le  1/2=(1-1/3)(1-1/4) $

Comment: It seems to me that if the conjecture with less-than-or-equal fell to the first possible counterexample, then it's a good idea to check for simple counterexamples before making a conjecture with less-than. There is no evidence that this has been done. Why present a conjecture with no reason to think it's true?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why the answer true? I think the answer is not valid. Because the case  $2.6  \le 3.4$ so I can write: 
$(1−1/2)(1−1/6)=5/12≤1/2=(1−1/3)(1−1/4)$
.